$A-B$ positive semidefinite implies the number of nonnegative eigenvalues of $A$ is at least those of $B$?
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are n-by-n complex Hermitian matrices such that $A-B$ is positive semidefinite.
Can we conclude that the number of nonnegative eigenvalues of $A$ is at least as many as the nonnegative eigenvalues of $B$?
(I have a hunch that it is true, but I cannot prove it.)

The notion of positive semidefiniteness is defined only for Hermitian matrices. And since you say "nonnegative eigenvalues of $A$", I assume you want both $A$ and $B$ to be Hermitian matrices?

Yes I will edit

Follows from Weyl's inequality.
Consider $M = A - B \Rightarrow A = M + B$.
$M$ is PSD, so consider the set of non-negative eigenvalues of $B$. For any eigenvalue $\lambda_i(B)$ in this set, the corresponding eigenvalue of $A$ can be shown to be, by the inequality,
$$\lambda_i(A) = \lambda_{i+n-n}(A) \geq\lambda_{n}(M) + \lambda_i(B),$$
implying that the LHS must be non negative since $M$ is PSD, giving us at least as many non negative eigenvalues as $B$.
